# How to apply BinCounts to weighted data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data

For example, I have an array:

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

and a corresponding list of weighting factors

```
weight = {5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1}
```

Evaluating

```
BinCounts[data, {1, 9, 1}]
```

gives

`{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`,

but

`{5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1}`

is the result wanted. How can I get this?

Comment: Presumably you've already tried to use `WeightedData[]`?

Comment: `BinCounts[
 Catenate@MapThread[ConstantArray, {data, weight}], {1, 9, 1}]`

Comment: With `WeightedData` you must use `Histogram` or `HistogramList`.  If the data points are all integers, use `Merge[Total]@Thread[data -> weight]`.

Comment: @ciao your solution works only with integer data and weights; could you please generalize it to non-integer data and weights?

Answer (score 8):

To formalize the comments, here is the complete code:

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
weight = {5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1};

Last[HistogramList[WeightedData[data, weight], 9]]
```

Which outputs

```
{5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, Young. Can the weighting factor be negative?

Comment: No. I didn't know that was a requirement

Comment: The data can be negative. The weights and data can be fractions.

Comment: @dudulu, exactly what application is having you consider negative weights?

Comment: @Young your solution works well. However, it is quite slower than `BinCounts`. Could you please think of other solutions which may be faster? I need to apply this function to very large datasets.