# How to optimize bin counts with weighted data

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118848/462) it is given a possible method in order to count data with weights. That solution works. However, it is ~140 times slower than the `Bincounts` function. See, e.g. the following code:

```
Ndata = 10^6;
SeedRandom[321];
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, Ndata];
weights = RandomReal[{.9, 1.1}, Ndata];
bins = Table[i, {i, 0, 10}];

AbsoluteTiming[Last[HistogramList[WeightedData[data, weights], {bins}]]]
AbsoluteTiming[BinCounts[data, {bins}]]
```

I would like to know if it is possible to make a faster function.

A faster method could be to apply the function proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135596/462) to the output of `BinLists`:

```
myFn = Merge[KeyIntersection[PositionIndex /@ {##}], Identity] &;
blist = BinLists[data, {bins}]
myFn[blist, Partition[data, 1]]
(*<|{0.986147} -> {{1}, {3}}, {1.49106} -> {{2}, {6}}, {3.23491} -> {{4}, {7}}, {7.15785} -> {{8}, {5}}, {8.9058} -> {{9}, {9}}|>*)
```

Then I could use the latter output (the positions) to sum the weights. However, `myFn` does not identify the positions if there are more elements inside a bin.

Does someone know how to improve upon this attempt? Other solutions are most welcome. Perhaps one could see how does the Python function `numpy.bincount` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a solution based on [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
wBinCounts[data_, weights_, bins_] := Module[{min, max, b, d},
    {min, max} = MinMax[data];
    If[min<0 && max>0,
        d = data - min + 1;
        b = bins - min + 1,
        d = data;
        b = bins
    ];
    With[{ranges = Partition[b, 2, 1]},
        Total @ Pick[weights, Unitize@Clip[d, {##}, {0, 0}], 1]& @@@ ranges
    ]
]
```

For your data:

```
Ndata=10^6;
SeedRandom[321];
data=RandomReal[{0,10},Ndata];
weights=RandomReal[{.9,1.1},Ndata];
bins=Table[i,{i,0,10}];

AbsoluteTiming[Last[HistogramList[WeightedData[data,weights],{bins}]]]
AbsoluteTiming[BinCounts[data, {bins}]]
AbsoluteTiming[wBinCounts[data,weights,bins]]
```

> {19.7562, {99667.3, 100028., 99756.9, 100022., 100024., 100361., 
>     100513., 99787.1, 99992.4, 99881.1}}
>
> {0.132353, {99688, 100024, 99735, 100031, 99998, 100371, 100488, 
>     99778, 100001, 99886}}
>
> {0.096202, {99667.3, 100028., 99756.9, 100022., 100024., 100361., 
>     100513., 99787.1, 99992.4, 99881.1}}

**Update**

`Clip[x, {min, max}]` uses $min \leq x \leq max$, and so values of $x$ at the end points will be included in both intervals. A slightly slower version of `wBinCounts` that avoids this issue (using $min \leq x < max$):

```
wBinCountsLeft[data_, weights_, bins_] := With[{ranges=Partition[bins,2,1]},
    Total @ Pick[
        weights,
        BitXor[UnitStep[Subtract[data, #1]], UnitStep[Subtract[data, #2]]],
        1
    ]& @@@ ranges
]
```

And a version using $min <x\leq max$:

```
wBinCountsRight[data_, weights_, bins_] := With[{ranges=Partition[bins,2,1]},
    Total @ Pick[
        weights,
        BitXor[UnitStep[Subtract[#1,data]], UnitStep[Subtract[#2,data]]],
        1
    ]& @@@ ranges
]
```

Example:

```
wBinCountsLeft[{1,1.5,2}, {1,1,1}, {0,1,2,3}]
wBinCountsRight[{1,1.5,2}, {1,1,1}, {0,1,2,3}]
```

> {0, 2, 1}
>
> {1, 2, 0}

Comment: Thanks! Could you please generalize it to the case of bins that are not unit intervals?

Comment: wow! it is even faster than `BinCounts`!

Comment: It seems as if a data point is counted twice if it lies at the bin boundary. For example, `wBinCounts[{1, 1.5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1, 2}]` returns `{1, 2}` but there are only 2 points in total. Could you please fix this?

Comment: thanks for the update! Could you please run the `AbsoluteTiming` of these new functions together with the old ones? I ran them on my Mac with Mathematica 11.3.0.0 and `BinCounts` got much faster. I believe I was using Mathematica 11.2.0.0 when I opened the question and I am not aware of any performance improvements regarding `BinCounts`.